# Как с помощью рефлексии определить какие методы класса относятся к определённому интерфейсу?

Tags: java, интерфейс, рефлексия

Создаю с помощью рефлексии экземпляр класса MBeanInfo и столкнулся с проблемой поиска методов реализующих определённый интерфейс. К примеру, имеется интерфейс `SimpleDynamicMBean` и класс `Simple` его реализующий. Согласно спецификации JMX имя интерфейса должно заканчиваться на `DynamicMBean` (для динамически управляемого ресурса), т.е. зная имя текущего класса, мы знаем какой интерфейс искать. Но как определить, что конкретный метод класса во-первых переопределён, а во вторых наследуется от определённого интерфейса?

```java
public interface SimpleDynamicMBean
{
    // read/write attribute path
    public String getPath();
    public void setPath( String path );

    // read/write attribute severityThreshold
    public int getSeverityThreshold();
    public void setSeverityThreshold( int threshold);

    // read/write attribute active
    public boolean isActive();
    public void setActive( boolean isActive );

    // read-only attribute changesCount
    public int getChangesCount();

    // write-only attribute
    public void setVerboseOutput( boolean isVerbose );


    // operation sendMessage
    public void sendMessage( String msg );

    // operation showSequenceNumber
    public int showSequenceNumber();
}
```

А также класс его реализующий:

```java
public class Simple implements SimpleDynamicMBean
{
    private int seq = 1;
    private boolean verboseOutput;
    private int changesCount;
    private String path;
    private int severityThreshold;
    private boolean active;

    public Simple ()
    {
        for( Method m : this.getClass().getMethods() )
        {
            // как определить, что метод m is overriden
            // и наследуется от SimpleDynamicMBean?
        }
    }

    @Override public String getPath()
    {
        return this.path;
    }
    @Override public void setPath( final String path )
    {
        this.path = path;
        this.changesCount++;
    }

    @Override public int getSeverityThreshold()
    {
        return this.severityThreshold;
    }
    @Override public void setSeverityThreshold( final int threshold )
    {
        this.severityThreshold = threshold;
        this.changesCount++;
    }

    @Override public boolean isActive()
    {
        return this.active;
    }
    @Override public void setActive( final boolean isActive )
    {
        this.active = isActive;
        this.changesCount++;
    }

    @Override public int getChangesCount()
    {
        return this.changesCount;
    }

    @Override public void setVerboseOutput( final boolean isVerbose )
    {
        this.verboseOutput = isVerbose;
        this.changesCount++;
    }

    @Override public void sendMessage( final String message )
    {
        System.out.println( message );
    }

    @Override public int showSequenceNumber()
    {
        return this.seq;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Решил с помощью получения списка всех интерфейсов класса и их последующей фильтрацией, т.к. имя искомого интерфейса задаётся спецификацией и может быть создано исходя из имени класса. Далее уже просто ищем подходящий метод в классе.

На счёт аннотации @Override так и не смог найти решение, так как она не доступна во время выполнения и не может быть определена/прочитана с помощью рефлексии.

```java
Class<?> cls = Simple.class;

String interfaceName = cls.getSimpleName() + "DynamicMBean";

Class<?> interfaceType = Stream.of( cls.getInterfaces() )
                        .filter( i -> i.getSimpleName().equals( interfaceName ) )
                        .findAny()
                        .orElseThrow( () -> new IntrospectionException( "..." ) );

for( Method interfaceMethod : interfaceType.getMethods() )
{
    Method clsMethod = clsMethods
                    .stream()
                    .filter( m ->
                        m.getName().equals( interfaceMethod.getName() )
                        &&
                        // проверяем сигнатуру метода...
                        Arrays.equals(
                            interfaceMethod.getParameterTypes(),
                            m.getParameterTypes()
                        )
                    )
                    .findAny()
                    .orElseThrow( () -> new IntrospectionException( "..." ) );
}
```